# scala doesn't like self variable in akka?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

```
import actors.Actor
import akka.actor.Actor._
class HelloWorldActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg => self reply (msg + "world")
  }
}
remote.start("localhost",9999).register(
  "hello-service", actorOf[HelloWorldActor]
)
```

I'm getting the follow error with my code:
error: not found: value self

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that's because you've imported Scala Actors:

`actors.Actor`

and then try to create an instance of it using Akka.

If you change:

`actors.Actor`

to

`akka.actor.Actor`

everything will be just fine.

Comment: error: class file needed by MessageInvocation is missing.
reference type Serializable of package scala refers to nonexisting symbol.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use Akka 1.1 with Scala 2.8.1